# A loop to created multiple output files stops at only one

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have a vba module in Excel that had worked a few years ago but not now. I think something has changed (or someone made a change) but I am not sure what. The module is intended to compare the data in Column B (pre-sorted); for each single row or multiple row that matches it outputs a txt file. The first file whether a single row or multiple row is being created but then it stops. It does not go to the next row or group of rows and create a second file (.etc).

The code:

```
Sub OrderEC()

    Dim Header(1 To 50) As Variant
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim txt As String
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim Rng3 As Range
    Dim Count() As Variant
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Users As Integer

    For i = 1 To 50
        Header(i) = Cells(1, i)
    Next

    Set Rng1 = Range("B2:B10000")
    For Each cell In Rng1
        If cell.Value = "" Then GoTo First

        ReDim Preserve Count(0 To 1, 0 To x) As Variant

        For i = 0 To x - 1
            If cell.Value = Count(1, i) Then
                Count(0, i) = Count(0, i) + 1
                GoTo First
            End If
        Next i

        Count(1, x) = cell.Value
        Count(0, x) = 1

        x = x + 1

First:
    Next

    Users = UBound(Count, 2)
    EndRow = 1

    For s = 1 To Users
        StartRow = EndRow
        EndRow = StartRow + Count(0, s - 1)

        DataFile = "C:\ECorder\" & "BULK_" & Cells(StartRow + 1, 2).Value & "_" & Format(DateTime.Now, "DDMMYYHHMMSS") & ".bulk"

        Open DataFile For Output As #1
        For U = 1 To 30
            Print #1, Header(U) & "=" & Cells(StartRow + 1, U)
        Next U

        For v = 31 To 40
            txt = Header(v) & "="
            For i = 1 To Count(0, s - 1)
                If i = 1 Then
                    txt = txt & Cells(StartRow + i, v)
                Else
                    txt = txt & ", " & Cells(StartRow + i, v)
                End If
            Next i
            Print #1, txt
        Next v

        For w = 41 To 44
            Print #1, Header(w) & "=" & Cells(StartRow + 1, w)
        Next w
        Close #1
    Next s

End Sub
```

Comment: have you actually debugged the code - stepped through line-by-line to compare expected vs actual behavoir?

Comment: Have you tried making your code run with the host workbook only?  As the only info I have is that a new workbook opens and your code stops, then maybe it's trying to run the info in the new workbook and stops.

Comment: I have debugged line-by-line but when it gets to the next to the last line

Next s

it goes directly to:

End Sub

without loopimg back for the next group.

Also only one sheet exists with no other woorbooks open

Comment: What is the value of `Users` when it is set?  (It appears it should be one less than the number of unique non-blank cells in B2:B10000 of the sheet which is active when you start the macro.)  If it is 1 (i.e. you have two unique non-blank values), you would expect your `For s` loop to only execute once.

Comment: It is a valie of 1

Comment: I created a new spreadsheet and entered fresh vba:

Now it works. Hmm.  Thanks for the help.